# Banshee won't start anymore

Tags: linux, mono-framework, banshee

Banshee 1.4.3 won't start anymore. I've tried debugging with --debug option at the terminal but no error message pops up.

Could it be the latest updates to mono?

I am running Jaunty Ubuntu 9.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upgrading to 1.5.0 on the PPA channel solves the problem.